# ng-options ignore the $localStorage Array when Refreshing the page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-storage

I've created a Plunkr. I'm pushing the item when click on the button and button color will change to red and splice the item in array when click on the same button the color of button will change to the green.

Problem is storage done perfectly. button $localStorage.tableArray not working with the selected ng-options.

when i refresh the page color of the button also fixed with ng-storage and ng-options will be stay.

[1st plunker is with ng-storage](https://plnkr.co/edit/Iz4Dk0Yi0HHXW52cVU8m?p=preview),
[2nd plunker is with arrays](https://plnkr.co/edit/ltMzNdAszTaOa1coJD6Y?p=preview)
please help me.

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', ["ngStorage"]);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$localStorage) {

     $scope.tablelist = [{"tablename":"t1"},{"tablename":"t2"}];

     if($localStorage.tableArray === undefined){
        $localStorage.tableArray = []
     }

     if($localStorage.tableslist === undefined){
         $localStorage.tableslist = []
     }

     $scope.getTable=function(table) {

         table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "btn-danger" ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger"
         var exists = false;

         angular.forEach($localStorage.tableArray, function (list,$index) {
            if ((list.tablename == table.tablename)) {
                console.log(list.tablename);
                console.log(table.tablename);
                exists = true;
                $localStorage.tableArray.splice($index,1);
                $scope.$storage=$localStorage.tableArray
                $localStorage.tableArray.splice($index,1);
                return false;
            }
        });

        if(!exists) {
            $localStorage.tableslist.push(table);
            $localStorage.tableArray = $localStorage.tableslist;
            console.log($localStorage.tableArray)
            table.color = "red"
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, it seems that you need to save not only the state of active buttons, but state of selected item in $localStorage. You can create some variable like `selected` in localStorage, and update it once user change select option with a help of `ng-change` directive. And you should get this var from LS on the init of controller, and set to you select model variable. This should works, I it will not help,  I can provide an example

Comment: my problem is when refreshing the page ng-options not visible and again i push the another value into $localStorage the previous  values  also visible. the color of the button will back to default color when refreshing the page.                                                                                                    please provide any plunker exmple regarding this